# term clustering library?

Tags: text-processing, information-retrieval, text-mining, text-analysis

Does anybody know an open-source\free library that does term clustering?

Thanks,
yaniv

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Mahout](http://lucene.apache.org/mahout/) provides algorithms for clustering.

Comment: thanks. it might be helpfull, but i'm looking for something specific for term clustering.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/). There's a number of [clustering](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/toc-nltk.cluster-module.html) modules that might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

[WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) has a whole suite of tools for text processing along with clustering.

Answer (score 0):

If your in to python there is NLTK, as already mentioned by it's author, but there is also [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn)  which provides much more than just clustering. ([Link](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/feature_extraction.html#applications-and-examples) takes you to text applicable examples).

Answer (score 0):

Python [Scikit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) has some dedicated packages for [text analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html). Besides they have a complete suite of Clustering Algorithms that includes [K-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means), [AP](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#affinity-propagation), [Mean shift](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mean-shift), [Spectral Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#spectral-clustering), [Hierarchical Clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering) and [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan) algorithms (with appropriate [evaluation metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering-performance-evaluation)). This may be helpful your term clustering task.

Link to [Scikit Learn latest video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjAB45qsx_c)

Link to [Scikit Learn Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783281936)